# Display simple raster file in openlayers

Tags: postgis, raster, openlayers, openlayers-2, postgis-raster

I have raster files ([one sample can download from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ZuhVpEHpSHajJBMGkzNU5rSWM/view?usp=sharing)) just have values for points and in beside i have top-left and bottom-right geo data and pixel size of file.
so i want to just simply display this in openlayers 3.
if i can choose colors for high and low values it will be good.
in server side i can access postgis and all it's raster functions.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Openlayers can't display Raster files as is. You need to publish your data through a web services. There is a lot different service you can use (WMTS, TMS, WMS). The simpliest is the Web Map Service (WMS).

I suggest you to have a look to [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) or [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/).

Comment: Many thanks. Can you please help me to publish this structured file with Geoserver? automatic from postgis and run in openlayers.

Comment: Sorry I do not use Geoserver since quite a long time. I suggest you ask this kind of thing on geoserver users list